# Matrix which represents the product of ideal classes of 2 matrices.

Tags: matrices, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible monic degree $n$ polynomial with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients and $\Theta$ be a root of $f(x)$.

There is an old theorem of Latimer and MacDuffee that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the similarity classes of integral matrices with characteristic polynomial $f(x)$ and $C(\mathbb{Z}[\Theta])$, the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\Theta]$.

If $f(x)=x_n+a_{n-1}x_{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$, then a matrix which corresponds to the identity of $\mathbb{Z}[\Theta]$ is the companion matrix of $f(x)$,

\begin{equation*}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
-a_0&-a_1&-a_2&\cdots &-a_{n-2}&-a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Also,  if $[I_X]\in C(\mathbb{Z}[\Theta])$ corresponds to a matrix $X$, then $[I_X]^{-1}=[I_{X^T}]$. That is, the ideal class corresponds to the transpose of $X$ is the inverse of the ideal class corresponds to $X$. This is due to Taussky.

**Question:** Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices with characteristic polynomial $f(x)$. How can we find a matrix $X_{A,B}$ such that $[I_{X_{A,B}}]=[I_A][I_B]\in C(\mathbb{Z}[\Theta])$? Are there any known results about this?